# Problems with Azure AD authentication (libpam-aad, libnss-aad) ubuntu 23.04 on Intel Core i5

Tags: intel, 23.04, azure

I have configured this authentication in AMD computers without any problem, but when I do it in several Intel, in all of them it gives me problems, it prevents me from configuring the system through the graphical environment, applications close, others do not open... does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].